# An issue with foreach loops and SQL (PDO)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I'm new here and this is my first question :)

I have this code:

```
<?php                   
/*
* Load messages from right users
*/
try {
    $selectContactQuery = 'SELECT profile_id, user_id  
        FROM profilecontact
        WHERE profile_id=:profile_id AND owner_id=:owner_id;';

    $prepSelectContacts = $conn->prepare($selectContactQuery);
    $prepSelectContacts->bindParam(':profile_id', $urlPid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $prepSelectContacts->bindParam(':owner_id', $uid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $prepSelectContacts->execute();
    $contactsResult = $prepSelectContacts->fetchAll();
    $contactsCount = count($contactsResult);
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    $conn = null;
    header('Location: ../errors/error_101.html');
}

foreach($contactsResult AS $contactsRow) {
    $scrapProfileId = $contactsRow['profile_id'];
    $scrapUserId = $contactsRow['user_id'];

    $selectScrapQuery = 'SELECT scraps.user_id, scraps.scrap_text, scraps.profile_id, scraps.add_date, user.user_id, user.profile_picture_50
        FROM scraps
        JOIN user ON(scraps.user_id = user.user_id) 
        WHERE scraps.user_id = scraps.user_id AND scraps.profile_id = scraps.profile_id ORDER BY add_date';
    $prepSelectScrap = $conn->prepare($selectScrapQuery);
    $prepSelectScrap->bindParam(':scraps.user_id', $scrapUserId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                $prepSelectScrap->bindParam(':profile_id', $scrapProfileId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $prepSelectScrap->execute();
    $scrapResult = $prepSelectScrap->fetchAll();
    $scrapResultCount = count($scrapResult);

    if($scrapResultCount > 0) {
        foreach($scrapResult AS $scrapResultRow) {
            echo '<div class="parentArrow"></div>
            <div class="scrapItemParent">
            <img class="scrapProfilePic" src=" ' . $scrapResultRow['profile_picture_50']. '" />
            <div class="scrapContent">' . $scrapResultRow['scrap_text'] . '<br />
            <span class="scrapTime">' . $scrapResultRow['add_date'] . '<br />' .  $scrapResultRow['user_id'] . ' ' . $scrapResultRow['profile_id'] . '</span></div></div>';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

What I'm trying to do is with the first SQL query, I try to select the contacts of one user and a specific profile he/she is associated with. This gives me a resultset that looks like:

```
+-----------+---------+
|profile_id | user_id |
+-----------+---------+
| 32        |  45     |
| 32        |  56     |
| 32        |  78     |
+-----------+---------+
```

I get these results with a foreach, which you can see in my code starting on the line that says "foreach ($contactsResult AS $contactsRow)..." Within this foreach loop, I execute an SQL query to load messages from the users that are associated with the right profile (the first SQL query is to load the users and their associated profiles). However, I have multiple issues with this. First of all, in the second SQL query, there is the WHERE clause that says:

```
"WHERE scraps.user_id = scraps.user_id AND scraps.profile_id = scraps.profile_id"
```

However, the second WHERE condition, with scraps.profile_id... is being ignored. The messages are also being displayed multiple times (twice when I test it).

Does anyone know what's wrong with this code? It doesn't give me any errors, it just won't do what I want it to do. I know that most of these issues are because of the loops, but I can't see another way of achieving what I need.

Comment: In the second where condition..you are forgetting the " : " like:-
"WHERE scraps.user_id =:scraps.user_id AND scraps.profile_id =:scraps.profile_id"

Comment: Now it says paramater not defined, on the line with ->execute. When I remove ":", it works (not as I intend, but okay...).

Comment: Something is not right with that logic, I am sure you can get this data using a single query, Selecting in a loop just doesnt feel right

Comment: I know, it doesn't feel right for me either, but the problem is that every message has a different origin. So the query has to be executed multiple times while the parameters in the WHERE clause are being updated with the next value in the array that was created by query number 1. I don't see any other way to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this out

```
 $selectScrapQuery = 'SELECT scraps.user_id, scraps.scrap_text, scraps.profile_id, scraps.add_date, user.user_id, user.profile_picture_50
                                            FROM scraps
                                            JOIN user ON(scraps.user_id = user.user_id) 
                                            WHERE scraps.user_id =:scraps_user_id AND scraps.profile_id =:scraps_profile_id ORDER BY scraps.add_date';
            $prepSelectScrap = $conn->prepare($selectScrapQuery);
            $prepSelectScrap->bindParam(':scraps_user_id', $scrapUserId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $prepSelectScrap->bindParam(':scraps_profile_id', $scrapProfileId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Comment: Thx but no difference :(

Comment: I checked your code now. It shows some kind of result. I can at least bind a value to the parameters. But I have to try and figure it out and if it won't work I'll try to figure out the issue then. THX!

Comment: All right, thx for your help. The updated code you provided has helped a lot, compared to what I had before. There are some minor issues, but there are other people on SO who also need help, so I'll figure those issues out myself. Thank you very much for your help, and the others here too :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to enter your php variables into the query

```
WHERE scraps.user_id = scraps.user_id AND scraps.profile_id = scraps.profile_id
```

This will allways equal true because `scraps.user_id = scraps.user_id` is comparing something to itself

You can use:

```
WHERE scraps.user_id = :scrapUserId AND scraps.profile_id = :scrapProfileId
```

Here I've input the variables `:scrapUserId` and `:scrapProfileId` into your query.
This will enable you to set these values with these statements:

```
$prepSelectScrap->bindParam(':scrapUserId', $scrapUserId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$prepSelectScrap->bindParam(':scrapProfileId', $scrapProfileId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but when I edit my code according to your anwer, it doesn't show anything anymore.

Comment: Is it possible that none of the records on your database match your query?

Comment: They do. There are rows of messages/scraps that have profile_id 51 for example. And also 53, 54, 56. But I just can't manage to only display the rows that have profile_id 51, 52. It only display all of them and sometimes it even display one row multiple times :O